# Which pattern is appropriate for my project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've been seeing a lot of articles and references about how to use this patterns for my first (please keep this in mind) serious project with ASP.NET MVC 3 and EF.

The project is not so big (13 tables) and it's basically a CRUD maintenance: organisations that have some users; users that can belong to a group and can create some work areas and templates... Nothing complicated. The point is that this will be the first of a project series and I'd like to create a base to work with.

My questions are:

Which of the previous patterns is the best? Does it depend of the project size?

My models would be these:

- [Unit of work](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)
- [Dependency Injection](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/aspnet/diwithmvc3.aspx)

Do you think they are good enough and appropriate for my project?

I appreciate all your comments.

Comment: Check out NerdDinner, it's a great place to start.  More advanced, check out codecampserver.

Answer (score 5):

*Serious* application doesn't mean to be complex at first sight.

Over engineering an application upfront can be a real disaster, especially if you don't grasp all the technologies involved.

My advice would be to [keep it simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Create a basic application that fulfill requirements (get the thing done and make your boss happy) and then add new concepts along your learning path.

That doesn't mean I promote bad code, no way! Keep your code clean, well organized, etc. But don't be killed by the fear of doing something wrong.

It's normal for a developer to look back to an application made a few weeks ago and then realize that he did some shitty stuff. That's how we progress!

Last but not least, have FUN!

[ASP.NET website](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/overview) provides usefull resources to learn the framework and all related guidances. There are a few application samples created step-by-step.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC was built with Dependency Injection in mind.

If you want to give a chance to your code to be loosely coupled and easier to change in the future you have to follow the patterns like Dependency Injection, Repository (for presistance abstraction), and UoW (for transaction abstraction).

So my answer is, you should learn about them in the first place to decide after if you want or no to follow the best practices. Even for simple project it's good to apply these patterns because often it gets bigger and bigger. and it's easy to do it in MVC so why to avoid it ?

There is many resources around to learn about. You can just google it.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to answer this question in more generic way. Creating something which can be used in future is difficult than what it seems. All the pattern above can provide you infrastructure pieces to come up with some base framework. 
But I would strongly suggest you to look at [S.O.L.I.D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principals (DI being part of it) to understand some qualities of good code. These are applicable irrespective of the technology involved.
You cannot predict the future requirement of a product\framework, but following these principle you can be better prepare to handle any future modification to the software

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [S#arp Lite](https://github.com/codai/Sharp-Lite) which has many good examples of how to implement the things you want and can serve as a very good base on which to build something quickly.

Answer (score 0):

None of the mentioned patterns are mutually exclusive. You should use the patterns that make sense based on what you are trying to accomplish, not attempt to shoehorn your application design into someone elses idea of how it should work. Sometimes trying to bend your scenario to fit a particular design pattern / practice is the worst thing you can do.

Want to make sure good unit test coverage / do TDD / ensure loose coupling? Then Dependency injection is your friend, as is the Unit of Work pattern. This is definitely a good idea for creating a maintainable, scalable application, but you can go too far with it for a small-scale application.

Need a centralized caching strategy for your data source? Then use the repository pattern. Or an ORM like NHibernate, which might do it for you.